# Does $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ injective and $Df[U]\subset{GL}_N(\mathbb{R})$ implies a local diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:U\subseteq \Bbb R^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ ($U$ open) a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function. Im suposed to show that if $f$ is injective and $Df(a)\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$ for all $a\in U$, therefore $f:U\longrightarrow f[U]$ are an $\mathcal{C}^1$ diffeomorphism.

Like, wat tool's i need to use to show that $f^{-1}$ are indeed diferentiable ?

Comment: Locally, this is a consequence of the inverse function theorem.

Comment: $f$ is thus open and it is a global diffeomorphism onto its image.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are referring to would be the [inverse function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).  In addition to being $C^1$ and injective,  you need the Jacobian determinant (the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$) to be nonzero.  Then $f$ will be a local diffeomorphism.

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2827831/403337) an example.

Comment: But why does $f$ be a local diffeomorphism ? If it is $\mathcal C^1$, $f$ has to be differentiable. Since $Df[U]\subset GL_n(\Bbb R)$ i see that $f$ has to be homeomorphism, but why the inverse are diferentiable ? I can't see how to prove it.

Comment: There is a proof in Chapter $9$ of Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_.  Since $f$ is injective , it's invertible.   Write $f\circ f^{-1}(x)=x$ and differentiate, using the chain rule.  You get a formula for $Df^{-1}$.

Comment: The hard part is the existence of $Df^{-1}$.